# Vue+Express+Axios Host Access to Guest App in Virtualbox getting CORS Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, virtualbox

I was unable to access my Vue app in Virtualbox from the host, both are using Linux Mint 20. I am now able to access the login page from my host but I keep getting a CORS error when trying to login:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

Host Headers:

```
{
    "OPTIONS": {
        "scheme": "http",
        "host": "localhost:3000",
        "filename": "/login"
    }
} 
{
"Transferred": "0 B (0 B size)",
"Referrer Policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
}

OPTIONS /login undefined
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: http://localhost:8080/login
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Guest Headers:

```
{
    "OPTIONS": {
        "scheme": "http",
        "host": "localhost:3000",
        "filename": "/login",
        "remote": {
            "Address": "127.0.0.1:3000"
        }
    }
}
{
    "Status": "204No Content",
    "Version": "HTTP/1.1",
    "Transferred": "374 B (0 B size)",
    "Referrer Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
}


HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 19:48:16 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

OPTIONS /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I am using a NAT and have port forwarding set up with host and guest using port 8080 but I have also tried a Bridged Adaptor.

package.json:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
```

Server Code:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:8080' , credentials: true }));
app.options('*', cors());

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    db.selectByEmail(req.body.email).then((response) => {
        ...
    }).catch((response) => {
        ...
    });
});

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port)
});
```

Request from Vue:

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
})
.then(response => {
    ...
})
.catch(function (error) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to get it working. I changed the VM network setting back to Bridged Adaptor and changed `localhost` to the VMs IP in my server call from Vue.

```
this.$http.post('http://192.168.1.x:3000/login', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to allow all headers?

```
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that and many other suggestions that I have found but none have worked